# Only pushing a single element to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a component which you can toggle on/off by clicking on it:

```
clickHandler = () => {
    this.setState({active: !this.state.active})
    this.props.getSelection(this.state.active)
}

render() {
    const { key, children } = this.props;
    return (
        <button
            key={key}
            style={{...style.box, background: this.state.active ? 'green' : ''}}
            onClick={() => this.clickHandler()}
        >
            {children}
        </button>
    );
}
```

In the parent component, I pass down a method in order to *try* and get the value of the selected element pushed into an array, like so:

```
getSelection = (val) => {
    const arr = []
    arr.push(val);
    console.log(arr, 'arr');
}
```

My problem is that it only ever adds one element to the array, so the array length is always 1 (even if more than one item has been clicked).

#### Current result (after you've clicked all three)

```
console.log(arr, 'arr') // ["Birthday"] "arr"
```

#### Expected result (after you've clicked all three)

```
console.log(arr, 'arr') // ["Birthday", "Christmas", "School achievement"] "arr"
```

Link to [Codepen](https://codepen.io/A7DC/pen/pYXKyB?editors=0001)

Any ideas?

Comment: every time `{
    const arr = []

    arr.push(val);

    console.log(arr, 'arr')
  }` is called, it creates an empty array, to which you push a single item, so, of course it's always 1 length - you'll need to declare `arr` **outside** of that function

Comment: Try defining the arr contant outside of the getSelection function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:
setState is async, so on the next line you might or might not get the latest value, so I recommend changing

```
clickHandler = () => {
    this.setState({active: !this.state.active})
    this.props.getSelection(this.state.active)
  }
```

to

```
clickHandler = () => {
   this.setState({active: !this.state.active}, () => {
      this.props.getSelection(this.state.active)
   })
}
```

The second argument to the setState is a callback function that will be executed right after the setState is done.

The second thing, on `getSelection` you are defining a new array each time you get there, so it won't have the values from the previous run. You should store it somewhere.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it helped.
If you want to keep track of the selected items you might need something like that:
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/nicolas-amabile/pen/OqeEvB?editors=0011)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems here:

1. `arr` is local variable. It doesn't keep the previous `onClick` result.
2. `setState` is an asynchronous event. According to [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

   > setState() does not always immediately update the component.

   `setState((state, props) => {}, () => { /*callback */})` should be used.

```
class Box extends React.Component {
  state = {
    active: false
  };

  clickHandler = () => {
    this.setState(
      state => ({ active: !state.active }),
      () => {
        this.props.getSelection(this.state.active);
      }
    );
  };

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;
    return (
      <button
        style={{ ...style.box, background: this.state.active ? "green" : "" }}
        onClick={this.clickHandler}
      >
        {children}
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

*Minor note:*

The `key` value isn't in the child component's `this.props`, so you don't have to pass it, but it will not affect the outcome.

In `App` component, let's create an array in class level for the sake of display:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    needsOptions: ["Birthday", "Christmas", "School achievement"]
  };

  arr = [];

  getSelection = val => {
    this.arr.push(val);
    console.log(this.arr);
  };
}
```

[CodePen here](https://codepen.io/changx03/pen/bZPKmJ?editors=1011)